# How to get measurement data like the distance between two points?

Tags: python, measurement

How to get measurement data like the distance between two points? I'd like to display them in addon as
name1: 142.354mm
name2:236.977mm
name3:201.364mm
...
thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MeasureData are stored in     `bpy.data.grease_pencils["Annotations"].layers['RulerData3D']`

[image]

MeasureLines are stored in StrokeCollections with Stroke Points. Every StrokePoint is stored with coordinates. With this coordinates we can calculate the length.

```
import bpy

idx = 0
for stroke in bpy.data.grease_pencils["Annotations"].layers['RulerData3D'].frames[0].strokes:
    print("name%s: %.3f mm" % (idx+1, (stroke.points[0].co - stroke.points[-1].co).length*1000))
    idx +=1
```

Return:

[image]

related: [How do I access grease pencil data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142190/how-do-i-access-grease-pencil-data)

**Update: get line and angle measurements**

MeasureData of lines are stored as Grease Pencil Strokes with 2 points.

MeasureData of angles are stored with 3 items. To get an angle we need two vectors [point0:point1] and [point2:point1] and calculate the angle with the build-in 'mathutils' module.
[image]

```
import bpy

idx = 0
for stroke in bpy.data.grease_pencils["Annotations"].layers['RulerData3D'].frames[0].strokes:

  # measure lines with 2 points:
    if len(stroke.points) == 2:   
        print("name%s(line): %.3f mm" % (idx+1, (stroke.points[0].co - stroke.points[-1].co).length*1000))

  # measure angles with 3 points) ; point[1] = mid point
    elif len(stroke.points) == 3:  
        vec1 = stroke.points[0].co - stroke.points[1].co   # first vec:  point[0] to point[1]
        vec2 = stroke.points[2].co - stroke.points[1].co   # second vec: point(2] to point[1]
        import mathutils  
        radians = mathutils.Vector((vec1)).angle(mathutils.Vector((vec2)))  # get radians
        import math
        angle = math.degrees(radians)                                       # convert to degrees
        print("name%s(angle): %.f degrees" % (idx+1, angle))        

    idx +=1
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works well.
And how can I find 'angle measurement' data? It's likely different from measureLines.

Comment: We need 2 points for a line, but three for an angle measurement (better 2 vectors). So we can detect an angle because of the three items (points) in a Grease Pencil Stroke. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much.